# How to use ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso as a live CD

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, live-cd

I am planning the upgrades of my MythTV box and laptop from 16.04 to 20.04 via 18.04. I have downloaded the .iso images for both releases, burnt them to a DVD, and tried them on the laptop prior to upgrading the MythTV system. 18.04.5 was fine, but the 20.04.2.0 doesn't seem to have an option to use it as a live CD. Am I missing something or is there an alternative image?

The 20.04 boot menu has the options *Ubuntu*, *Ubuntu (safe graphics)*, *OEM Install (for manufacturers)*, *Boot from next volume*, *UEFI Firmware Settings)*, i.e. there is not an option to *Try Ubuntu without installing*.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include details about the exact problem that you are facing.  You should be able to boot a DVD and run a live session if you burned the ISO to that DVD.  Keep in mind that it will take a long time to load due to the slow read speeds of DVD media.

Comment: Just to clarify my post:-

Comment: Just to clarify my post, the 18.04 DVD boot menu has the options "Try Ubuntu without installing", Install Ubuntu", "OEM Install (for manufacturers), and "Check disc for defects". The 20.04 boot menu has the options "Ubuntu", "Ubuntu (safe graphics)", "OEM Install (for manufacturers)", "Boot from next volume", "UEFI Firmware settings). I.E. there is not an option to "Try Ubuntu without installing".

Comment: You are just confused: On 20.04 "Ubuntu" will start the live session. It does not start an installation unless you click "Install Ubuntu" on the desktop.

Comment: @Nmath not always! The thing is the distro is the same but it comes with some pre programmed code which first identifies the machine and if it's compatible shows determined options.

Comment: Its most like this Ubuntu distro isn't meant for live tests but you still will able to install it

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any of the options in the GRUB boot menu, but don't select the *OEM install (for manufacturers)* option. Selecting the *Ubuntu* option will start an Ubuntu live session. From the Ubuntu live session you can click the *Install Ubuntu* icon on the desktop to start the Ubuntu installer.